# Retrieve Tags from db phalcon

Tags: php, mysql, database, tags, phalcon

I'm implementing a blog with phalcon. there have a tag field followed by:
https://github.com/mfiels/tagsly/blob/master/index.html

its insert multiple value into the db. but dont understand how to retrieve array value from tags field.

i want to render all tags list and if a user click on that tag, then it should render list of all related post. i mean in function im unable figure it $tags = Blogs::find(); how to find array value with like clause? Or am i going wrong? or is there any easy way? please...

[My db looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n9d3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
$result = Blogs::find([
    'tag LIKE :tag:',
    'bind' => ['tag' => $tag],
]);
```